# Lineaire transformation of matrices, how to tackle

Tags: matrices, transformation, linear-transformations

I've been learning linear algebra but can't understand the concepts of linear transformation.

Correct me where i'm wrong:

Say i'm given $T:R^2 \longrightarrow R^2$ is my transformation. This tells me it takes a matrix or vector with two rows, does something to it and returns a matrix with two rows again.

Further it is given *the translation occurs over the vector $(-4,2)^T$ and then mirrored in the line $x_2=-x_1$*. The transformed matrix must be in **homogeneous coordinates**.

What do we translate over the vector $(-4,2)^T$ and how does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't really clear... Based on what you wrote, my guess is that the linear transformation $T$ is the symmetry relatively to the line of equation $x_2 = -x_1$, and that you want to write its matrix $A$ in the natural base of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Recall that the two columns of the matrix $A$ are simply the images of the two base vectors $e_1 = (1,0)^T$ and $e_2 = (0,1)^T$ by the transformation $T$.

It is quite obvious *(do a drawing to be convinced of it!)* that $T(e_1)=-e_2 = (0,-1)^T$ and $T(e_2)=-e_1= (-1,0)^T$, so we have

$$ A = \left(\begin{array}{c c}
0 & -1 \\
-1 & 0
 \end{array} \right)$$

And if you want to compute the image of the vector $x = (-4,2)^T$ by the transformation $T$, just compute:

$$ T(x) = Ax =\left(\begin{array}{c c}
0 & -1 \\
-1 & 0
 \end{array} \right)  \left(\begin{array}{c }
-4 \\
2 
 \end{array} \right) =  \left(\begin{array}{c }
-2 \\
4 
 \end{array}\right) $$

Comment: Yes I can see it more clearly now, thnx